# how to add new Items to listview on a button click in uwp

Tags: uwp

I have  a Usercontrol which contains a listview and a button.

i want to list items to be automatically added in listview when button is clicked.

thank you

```
 public List<PhotosGrid> AddPicture = new List<PhotosGrid>();
 public EditPhotosUserControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "/Assets/FamilyOfficeImg/car1.png", placeHolder = "Car Side View", Caption = "Side View" });
            AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "/Assets/FamilyOfficeImg/interior.png", placeHolder = "Car Interior View", Caption = "Interior View" });
             PhotosGridView.ItemsSource = AddPicture;


        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "", placeHolder = "Car Interior View", Caption = "Interior View" });
            PhotosGridView.ItemsSource = AddPicture;


        }
 public class PhotosGrid
    {
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string placeHolder { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you currently have?

Comment: i want new item to be added automatically when addButton is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change your `PhotosGrid` Class to Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you do not need to repeatedly set `ItemsSource`.

Below is how I would do it.

```
public class PhotosGrid : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _picture;
    public string Picture
    {
        get { return _picture; }
        set { _picture = value; OnPropertyChanged("Picture"); }
    }

    private string _placeHolder;
    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return _placeHolder; }
        set { _placeHolder = value; OnPropertyChanged("PlaceHolder"); }
    }

    private string _caption;
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return _caption; }
        set { _caption = value; OnPropertyChanged("Caption"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Next, you need to change the `AddPicture` from `List` to [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) so that updating the list will fire [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) and `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be utilized. The official [Data Binding in Depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth?branch=master#binding-source) documentation has a table with all the necessary types for C#, C++, and CX.

So your `UserControl` will be:

```
public sealed partial class EditPhotosUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<PhotosGrid> AddPicture = new ObservableCollection<PhotosGrid>();
    public EditPhotosUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "", PlaceHolder = "Car Side View", Caption = "Side View" });
        AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "", PlaceHolder = "Car Interior View", Caption = "Interior View" });
        PhotosGridView.ItemsSource = AddPicture;
    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddPicture.Add(new PhotosGrid { Picture = "", PlaceHolder = "Car Interior View", Caption = "Interior View" });
    }
}
```

This will take care of your ***i want new item to be added automatically when addButton is clicked***

Final Output.

[image: gif of clicking the button and items appearing]

Good Luck.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, the key part of this answer for me was that the bound collection must be observable ([`ObservableCollection<PhotosGrid>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)). A plain `List<PhotosGrid>` does not work. The official [data binding documentation](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth?branch=master#binding-source) has a helpful table that explains which collection types handle which changes.

Comment: Would be nice to fix this link and then delete this comment:
Should be 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth