# Populating a listview in uwp with button press from textbox

Tags: listview, uwp

I'm trying to populate a list view in uwp from a textbox. But every time I press the Add button the words are stacking on each other. I mean it is populating the list view but it seems that it's populating it only on row number 1.
This is my code.

```
namespace Library
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        
         ListView Fruits;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Fruits = new ListView();

            
            Fruits.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
            FruitsPanel.Children.Add(Fruits);

        }
    }


    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add new Items to listview on a button click in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065278/how-to-add-new-items-to-listview-on-a-button-click-in-uwp)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Fruits = new ListView(); // at this line problem

    Fruits.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
    FruitsPanel.Children.Add(Fruits); // and this line too

}
```

What you are doing is every time `button` is clicked a new list View is being created. And an item is being added into it and also you are adding `ListView` to `Panel` every time for no reason . Instead what you need to do is this.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Fruits = new ListView(); // Initialize ListView from Constructor
    FruitsPanel.Children.Add(Fruits); // add ListView to Layout only once
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Fruits.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
}
```

What now we are doing is, basically Initializing a new instance of `Fruits ListView` only once when `MainPage` opens (Initiated). Instead of Initializing `ListView` every time button is clicked.

Now, On button click we are just adding new Item and not replacing previous whole listview.

Comment: I think you need to move the `FruitsPanel.Children.Add(Fruits);` also to the cosntructor. Otherwise you will not only add new items to the listview but also keep adding the listview to the panel.

Comment: oh yeah ofcource. I didn't even notice that line. just copy pasted.Thanks :)

Comment: @IliyaB if it worked for you please mark it as Answer ! Thanks :)